# Form reloads page 2nd time with preventDefault when using custom DOM function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a login form, and when submitted it calls this function

```
login = (that) ->
  header =
    "X-CSRFToken": window.csrftoken

  $('body').toggleDOM('.loading', true)

  fermata.json("/login").post(header, that, (err, data) ->
    $('body').toggleDOM('.loading', false)

    if !data.success
      htAlert.error 'Incorrect username and/or password.'
  )
```

This will add a "loading spinner" while the API is being called, and then it's removed. This works fine the first time you submit the form, because I'm using `preventDefault` so the page doesn't reload. However on the 2nd try, the page will reload, and I don't know why it's behaving like that.

My DOM function to add an element to the body:

```
$.fn.toggleDOM = (domName, b) ->
  dom = domName[domName.search(/([\.\#])/)]
  newDom = domName.substring(1)

  if dom == '#'
    if b
      document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="' + newDom + '"></div>'
    else
      document.getElementById(newDom).remove()
  else
    if b
      document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="' + newDom + '"></div>'
    else
      document.getElementsByClassName(newDom)[0].remove()
```

The event for form submit:

```
$ ->
  trigger = document.querySelectorAll("[data-trigger]")

  trigger.forEach((i) ->
     i.addEventListener "submit", (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      # We have to pass the event instead of the element.
      switch i.attributes["data-trigger"].nodeValue
        when "[form/login]" then login(e)
```

HTML:

```
<form data-trigger="[form/login]" class="login">
  <input type="hidden" class="uuid hidden">
  <input placeholder="Username" class="username">
  <input placeholder="Password" type="password" class="password">
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

I need to know why it reloads the page on the 2nd try. If I remove the `$('body').toggleDOM('.loading', true)` it does not behave like that and works as intended.

Also, I'm **not** using jQuery, I'm using this small library: https://github.com/finom/balalaika

Comment: Can you supply a HTML snippet as well or perhaps a working example?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson I added the HTML for the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you attach event listeners to your elements.
What you're trying to do doesn't work in plain JavaScript.

What you need to utilize is event delegation; it won't change much code wise but it'll change how it works.

By removing your for loop and attaching the handler to the `document` instead, you'll get what you're after.

```
document.addEventListener "submit", (e) ->
  e.preventDefault();
  switch e.target.attributes["data-trigger"].nodeValue
    when "[form/login]" then login(e)
```

There is a great article that covers [the how and why](https://gomakethings.com/listening-for-click-events-with-vanilla-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for the article, it's very interesting!